# regex for two groups, one is optional

Tags: r, regex

Working with the following sample data

```
mystr <- c("17RW001 30,9 1 HR L",
           "17RW001 130,9 1 HR L",
           "21RW001 1,6 +40 1 HR L",
           "21RW001 31,6 +4 1 HR L")
```

I want to extract some data from the strings. I am want to extract parts `30,9  130,9  1,6  and  31,6` (value in kilometers), and the (sometimes present, sometimes not) value after the `+`-sign (offset in meters).

After extraction the result has to be converted to numeric, the second group (if present) has to be divided by 1000 and added to the first group, so the following numeric output is created:

```
desired<- c(30.900, 130.900, 1.640, 31.604)
```

I am able to achieve this, but it take a lot more `gsub`'s and `ifelse`'s than I would like (first check if a `+...` is present, and then, and if not then, ... , paste together and convert to numeric. (note that in the sample data a comma is the decimal separator, so more gsubs needed ;-) ).

But i have the feeling that this can be done easier / more elegant. Is it possible to capture groups that are optional? I'm open to all solutions that transfer `mystr` to `desired` in a more elegant way than my current chunk of code.

Comment: Your data has a potential problem.  So far, we only see `+40` and `+4`, but could there for example ever be `+123`?  We need to know this, in order to process those numbers correctly.  My suggestion here: Go back to your source data and get a better export.  Even if that takes more time, in the end it will be less of a headache.

Comment: the numbers after + are always 99 or lower. Going back to export is (unfortunately)  not an option in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope this code help

```
sapply(
  strsplit(
    gsub(
      ",",
      ".",
      gsub(".*?(\\d+,\\d+\\s(\\+\\d+)?).*", "\\1", mystr)
    ), "\\s+"
  ),
  function(x) {
    sum(as.numeric(x) * c(1, ifelse(
      length(x) == 1, 0, 1e-3
    )))
  }
)
```

which gives

```
[1]  30.900 130.900   1.640  31.604
```

Comment: yes, works flawless (at least at several test-points) on  production dataset and is fast (enough) for my >100000 rows data.

Comment: also, love the use of `ifelse` here.. very clever!

Answer (score 2):

This is a rather brute force approach using 4 separate calls to `sub` for the various steps:

```
output <- sub("(?<=\\+)(\\d)(?=\\D)", "0\\1", mystr, perl=TRUE)
output <- sub("(?<=\\d)\\s+\\+(?=\\d)", "", output, perl=TRUE)
output <- sub("^.*\\b(\\d+,\\d+)\\b.*$", "\\1", output)
output <- sub(",", ".", output, fixed=TRUE)
output

[1] "30.9"   "130.9"  "1.640"  "31.604"
```

**Data:**

```
mystr <- c("17RW001 30,9 1 HR L",
           "17RW001 130,9 1 HR L",
           "21RW001 1,6 +40 1 HR L",
           "21RW001 31,6 +4 1 HR L")
```

Comment: works. also on my production data. The solution by @ThomasIsCoding is easier to add in my current `data.table` 'flow'. But a big thanks for your effords and a refresh of my knowledge of look-ahaed patterns ;-)

Comment: You should accept the @Thomas answer, but maybe keep this answer on tap in case the other answer misses some unforeseen edge case.